# How to write Model.clean() properly given invalid (unset) foreign-key form fields (Django)?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model with required `ForeignKey` fields (`null=False`, `blank=False` by default) that ends up in a form in the admin UI.

If I leave those fields blank in the admin UI and click "save", the form validation fails, but then the following unfortunate sequence happens:

1. Those fields are not checked by model clean fields ([link](https://github.com/django/django/blob/dbe263751cf80732c2cd47d409f5f0a9701ec327/django/forms/models.py#L403)):

```py
            # Exclude fields that failed form validation. There's no need for
            # the model fields to validate them as well.
            elif field in self._errors:
                exclude.add(f.name)
```

2. My custom model.clean is called with invalid form fields ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean)).
3. My custom model.clean raises an unexpected error because it's checking invalid foreign key fields set to strings (the error messages of the fields).

The workaround I found is to check if the field id is None (meaning the foreign key is not set), but it feels like a hack.

Is there a better way to deal with this?